# Google Calendar event from sheets script ends a day early

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have a sheets file that creates a calendar event when a button is clicked. The calendar event is based off of a user entered due date, and script created start date, a entered location, and an entered description all pulled from certain cells in the spreadsheet. The problem is that when I go to the calendar the event ends a day before the due date (or beginning of the day of the due date) and I want it to show for the entire due date. For example if I enter a due date of july 17th into the spreadsheet, when I create the calendar event it only runs through the 16th. Is there a way to get the events to schedule to the end of the day or an easy way to just offset the end date by one day in the script.

```
  var Description = sheetTemplate.getRange('B12').getValue(); //gets discription from Cell B12
  var Location = sheetTemplate.getRange('C5') .getValue();  //gets location of work order from cell C5
  var StartDate = sheetTemplate.getRange('C4').getValue();  //Start Date from Cell C4
  var DueDate = sheetTemplate.getRange('E5').getValue();    //Gets Due Date From Cell E5


     //This portion of the code schedules the WO on the calendar//

var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("XXXXX") ;//Get the Maintenance Calendar
var options = { 'location': Location, 
             'description':Description
            } //sets event details

var WOevent = eventCal.createAllDayEvent(WOname,StartDate,DueDate,options);//creates a calendar event

WOevent.setColor('10') // sets the color of the calendar event to green
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You have two options

- Either you manually add a day to the dueDate

This can be done with [`new Date(ms)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var DueDate = sheetTemplate.getRange('E5').getValue(); 
DueDate = new Date(DueDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
```

- Or you use the method [createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options) instead of `createAllDayEvent()`

This allows you to specify the end time on the DueDate:

```js
var DueDate = sheetTemplate.getRange('E5').getValue();
DueDate = new Date(DueDate);
DueDate.setHours(23);
DueDate.setMinutes(59);
var WOevent = eventCal.createEvent(WOname,StartDate,DueDate,options);
```

Comment: setting the time of the start and stop worked perfectly.